Make tab bar's selected tab underline be only as long as the label text
I want to be able to have the selected tab's underline within the tab bar to only be as long as the text for that tab (as shown below). I believe my issue is that I have a SizedBox with a defined width that uses the screen's width to determine the width of each tab. I did this since there would be a scroll with the "SHARE THE GOOD" tab as it's too long and I want all the tabs to fit on the screen with no scroll.

Here's the code I have for creating that tab bar
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  static TextStyle tabTextStyle = smallCaps13;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final List<Widget> tabs = [
      SizedBox(
        width: width * 0.25,
        // padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0),
        child: const Tab(child: Text("HOME")),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: width * 0.25,
        // padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0),
        child: const Tab(child: Text("NEWS")),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: width * 0.5,
        // padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0),
        child: const Tab(child: Text("SHARE THE GOOD")),
      ),
    ];
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
            splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
            labelStyle: smallCaps13.copyWith(color: ftiDarkBlue),
            unselectedLabelColor: ftiMediumGray,
            tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
            indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: tabs,
          ),
          const Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              children: [
                HomeTab(),
                NewsTab(),
                ShareTheGoodTab(),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I tried adding indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label, to no avail as it's still considering that whole SizedBox which makes sense.

You can have the default controller access like DefaultTabController.maybeOf(context) but you need to go one level down to the context tree. I would say use a TabController.
The constraints left on your custom width of the TabBar item which isn't equal to the text. You can build it with Row, you can use Row/Column.
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  static TextStyle tabTextStyle = const TextStyle();

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final tabTitles = ["HomeTab", "News", "Share the good"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///
    Widget _buildTab(int index, String text) {
      return Expanded(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            tabController.animateTo(index);
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Tab(
            child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: index == tabController.index
                  ? const BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          width: 2.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : const BoxDecoration(),
              child: Text(text, style: HomeScreen.tabTextStyle),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) _buildTab(i, tabTitles[i])],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: tabController,
            children: [
              Text("HOME"),
              Text("NEWS"),
              Text("SHARE THE GOOD"),
              // HomeTab(),
              // NewsTab(),
              // ShareTheGoodTab(),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}



Thanks for helping out :) that seemed to have worked wonderfully
